# Guardar inputs dinamicos en una BD

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Llevo un tiempo dandole vueltas de cómo se guardan inputs dinamicos en una base de datos. 
Me explico:

Tengo una base de datos con una extructura como la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien. Si tuviese en el formulario que registra estos datos, inputs generados por el cliente, el cual puede crear 1, 2, 5 o 10 campos extra. ¿Cómo los guardo en mi base de datos? ¿Los meto en un array? No se me ocurre cómo se puede hacer

Answer (score 0):

Yo crearia una string en la que codificaras los datos extra: `$string = "dato1;dato2;dato3"`, y eso se almacena en una columna. Luego usas `$variable = preg_split(";" $string);` lo cual te devolvería un array que se almacena en `$variable` y de esa manera puedes acceder a los datos